# Open another asp page depend on selected values in drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have one drop down with values No , Yes

After selecting the drop down and click the command button , then it should redirect to an asp page depend on the selected value in drop down

if Yes selected then after clicking command button redirect to abc.asp
if no selected then redirect to def.asp

But it is not redirecting to any page

```
<input type="submit" value ="continue" name="cmd" onclick="chkSite()">

function chkSite() {
    var lacCon = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;

    if (lacCon =="Yes") 
    {
        window.location.href = 'abc.asp'
    }
    else if (lacCon=="No")
    {
        window.location.href = 'def.asp'
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for dropdown list...is it html or asp drop down

Comment: I guess you need to make call to controller with selected value and in some kind of switch on the server side render wanted view.

Comment: Where is the element that has the id "dropdown"?
There is too much missing information to this question.

Comment: Please show the HTML of the dropdown list as well. Also, is any of this contained within a `<form>` tag? If so then a `<button type="submit"` will just submit the form directly without waiting for any JavaScript to run. You could change it to `<button type="button"` instead and see if that helps. But also...what debugging have you done? Have you stepped through the code using the JavaScript debugger (built into your browser) to see which code lines are executed and what the variable values are at that moment? Have you checked the console for errors? Lots more you could do yourself first.

Comment: @maximelian1986 OP clearly wants the code to go to two totally different URLs, not a single controller. Also they appear (from the .asp file extensions) to be using ASP Classic which, unless someone has recently written a whole MVC framework for a 20+-year-old legacy language, has no concept of controllers or views...there are just script files. So I'm not sure your comment makes much sense....

Comment: @ADyson Thanks . You are right. I changed to <input type ="button" and it works :)